# What is the exact word for the person who calls the speakers in an event using a mic?

Tags: british-english

What is a person who speaks on the mic that which person is going to come next to speak called?

Comment: From the wiki- In broadcast media a presenter is, especially in British English, the person who hosts, narrates, or otherwise takes the main role in presenting a radio or television programme. Not a stretch to apply it to other speaking presentations.

Comment: What sort of event? Academic conference? Quiz show? Wedding?

Comment: Its an academic conference.

Answer (score 9):

At many events (or just informally) this person is called the [MC](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/MC) or [Master of Ceremonies](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/master-of-ceremonies)

> **MC** *noun*
>   **1** short for **master of ceremonies**.
>   **2** a person who provides entertainment at a club or party by instructing the DJ and performing rap music.
>
> **Master of Ceremonies** *noun*
>   a person who presides over a formal event or entertainment and who introduces guests, speakers, or entertainers:
>      *the Master of Ceremonies will announce the cake-cutting*

There is also the word [***compere***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comp%C3%A8re).

> **compere** *noun*
>   a person who introduces the performers or contestants in a variety show.

Comment: It's also commonly spelled as *Emcee* which I think is more common in Britain.

Comment: I've never seen or used Emcee (and I'm in Britain). It's always MC.

Comment: I've come across it before, but pretty rarely here in the US.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Odd; I've seen [_emcee_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emcee) used both noun and verb here in the US. And [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/emcee) tags the word as "American."

Comment: WolframAlpha lists it as both, I just assumed it was slightly more popular there than here.

Comment: When someone is talking to me, I have trouble telling whether they are saying *MC* or *emcee*.

Comment: [Three MCs and One DJ](http://www.metrolyrics.com/three-mcs-and-one-dj-lyrics-beastie-boys.html) Apparently [peaked at 21](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Control_/_Three_MC's_and_One_DJ#Charts) on the British Singles chart. [RIP Adam Youch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XflfiylNNXY). To the point: I've only seen it written out *Emcee* when it's plural and the text needs to look professional (where some writing guidelines have a rule against acronyms). If it's singular the text would just say "Master of Ceremonies".

Answer (score 5):

If this person is directing speeches in a political context, they may be **the chair** (-woman or -man or -person) or (esp in British use) **the speaker**. In an academic setting, they may be **the moderator**.

Comment: Broader than political context, the Chair is generally the term for the person running a committee meeting. Corporate and social committees adhere to this as well. You also have a moderator (less often, a host) of debates or talk programs (radio, television etc.).

Answer (score 3):

MC (Master of Ceremonies) is a common word for that.  However, sometimes (especially in certain specfic contexts and settings) that person might simply be called a "host".

Answer (score 2):

A [master of ceremonies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_ceremonies) is the host of a staged event, whose duties include the presentation of speakers or performers. The term is not specific to British English. It's frequently abbreviated “MC” or “emcee” (and often applied metaphorically to rappers in hip-hop music).